# Update image source URL string only up to the image name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How can I replace URL address of an image source string only before the name of file?

Right now I am doing this like a hard coded way as `$('img').attr('src', add+"slide1.jpg");` but I need to get rid of the name of file in the JS part and just update the URL string before the name of files

```js
var add = "https://lamaisonduchien.ca/wp-content/uploads/revslider/home_1/";
$(".button").on("click", function(){
     $('img').attr('src', add+"slide1.jpg");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Update</button><br />
<img src="http://www.dpwts.com/slide1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="300">
<img src="http://www.aseanta.org/images/slide/slide1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="300">
```

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a regex to check for `jpg` or `gif` etc...:

[`^.+(?=.*\b.+\.(jpg|gif))`](https://regex101.com/r/dpkX4E/1)

- from the beginning of the string `^`
- take one or more characters `.+`
- use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if the string ends on .jpg or .gif

  - match a word boundary `\b`
  - take one or more characters `.+`
  - match a dot `\.`
  - followed by the extension `jpg` or `gif`

```js
var add = "https://lamaisonduchien.ca/wp-content/uploads/revslider/home_1/";
$(".button").on("click", function(){
    $('img').each(function(index, val) {
        var src = $(val).attr("src");
        var pattern = /^.+(?=.*\b.+\.jpg)/;
        $(val).attr("src", src.replace(pattern, add));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Update</button><br />
<img src="http://www.dpwts.com/slide1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="300">
<img src="http://www.aseanta.org/images/slide/slide1.jpg" alt="Smiley face" height="300" width="300">
```

Then you could use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the matches value with your `add` variable.